# WPF Modules in a Apps View

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, wpf-controls

I am in the early stages of designing a WPF MVVM application.  I will have several modules in my application and will be adding more in the future.  I want the home screen to feel almost like that of a tablet with the modules displayed as icons similar to apps on a tablet.  I was looking for some advise on what WPF control would best help me get this desired look and feel.      I would some advice on this and if anyone has a link to an example where some else has implemented something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest first you go and see how [Prism framework](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) works for a modular wpf application (one of the best architectures)

Secondly, your UI should be a hardcoded main screen with the tile icons for each module or wrappanel in itemscontrol with datatemplate defined as a tile. Also you can check [this sample](http://www.askvg.com/mosaic-get-windows-8-style-live-tiles-with-metro-ui-on-windows-7-desktop/) oriented in WinRT lookalike GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am planning to use the Prism framework